# Android orientation handling issue when there are many activities

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, android-manifest, fragment

I have a problem for screen orientation on Android development.

I have two activities and one is set like this: (on **AndroidManifest.xml**)

> android:screenOrientation="portrait"

and the other one is set like this:

> android:screenOrientation="fullUser"

And here's the application flow:

```
Start Application -> 1'st activity started
     -> Click a button -> a fragment started
          -> Click a button -> 2'nd activity started
```

And one more thing you have to know is that 2'nd activity has translucent configuration meaning behind fragment is visible, but not focused.

The problem is, when I turn on the screen rotation sensor, and rotate the device,
2'nd activity is rotated properly but behind fragment also re-created.
What I expected is that fragment is remained portrait, and only second activity
re-created landscape orientation.(I think 1'st activity also re-created but we can't
sure because it is hidden.)

I wanna know this is right behavior, and why it works like this? (give me documentations, or something reasonable reasons, etc.)
How should I do if I want fragment remains portrait and second activity changed landscape?

Comment: hi can you tell me that in which way you handled the fragment lifecycle methods??? please have a look on them...if possible share the code...make sure that fragment lefecycle is according and with respect to yours logic and program behavior.

Comment: add this `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` line to firstactivity in manifest.xml